# click_no_wait function is not available in watir_webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

This `click_no_wait` function is not working in `watir_webdriver`.

Is there any other functions are available to achieve the same work?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the `click_no_wait` method? As far as I recall, the main usage in Watir-Classic was to handle scenarios were clicking caused JavaScript alerts to appear. The click would block until the alert disappeared, which is why you needed to `click_no_wait`. Watir-Webdriver does not have the same blocking problem, so you can just use `click`.

Comment: hi, yep I noticed what you are talking now! My mistake is because I have written another statement using 'wait_until_present' directly below click, When program was waiting here I thought click function is blocked the execution.  Thank you!